# Can not use batching request in Google Classroom API

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, google-client, google-classroom

I'm using Google SDK PHP to execute get batching reques to get list of courses in Google Classroom. My script use service account to access sguite data without user comfirm. If I turn off batch mode, it run OK, but it has error when I turn on batch mode
Here is my code

```
<?php
namespace app\Libs;
use Google_Client;
use Google_Service_Classroom;


class ClassRoom

{


private $api, $adminEmail, $client;

const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.course-work.readonly','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses.readonly','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.me','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.me.readonly','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.students','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.students.readonly','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.emails','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.photos','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters.readonly','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.student-submissions.me.readonly','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.student-submissions.students.readonly','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.guardianlinks.students'];



function __construct($adminEmail)
{
    $this->adminEmail = $adminEmail;
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig('config.json');
    $client->setScopes(self::SCOPES);
    $client->setSubject($adminEmail);
    $this->api = new Google_Service_Classroom($client);
}


function addClasses()
{
    $client = $this->api->getClient();
    $client->setUseBatch(true);
    $batch = new Google_Http_Batch($client);
    $ownerId = 'admin@duongvanba.com';
    $x1 = new Google_Service_Classroom_Course(['name'=>'Math']);
    $x1->setOwnerId($ownerId);
    $r1 = $this->api->courses->create($x1);
    $batch->add($r1, "a");

    $x2 = new Google_Service_Classroom_Course(['name'=>'Geography']);
    $x2->setOwnerId($ownerId);
    $r2 = $this->api->courses->create($x2);
    $batch->add($r2, "b");

    $results = $batch->execute();
    var_dump($results);

    $client->setUseBatch(false);
    }
}

?>
```

When I use batching request with Google Calendar API, it's OK. But with Classroom API, i recevied results that

```
    object(Google_Service_Exception)#209 (8) {
  ["errors":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["message":protected]=>
  string(9) "Not Found"
  ["string":"Exception":private]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["code":protected]=>
  int(404)
  ["file":protected]=>
  string(71) "/home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php"
  ["line":protected]=>
  int(118)
  ["trace":"Exception":private]=>
  array(51) {
    [0]=>
    array(6) {
      ["file"]=>
      string(72) "/home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/Batch.php"
      ["line"]=>
      int(172)
      ["function"]=>
      string(18) "decodeHttpResponse"
      ["class"]=>
      string(16) "Google_Http_REST"
      ["type"]=>
      string(2) "::"
      ["args"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)#226 (6) {
          ["reasonPhrase":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=>
          string(9) "Not Found"
          ["statusCode":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=>
          int(404)
          ["headers":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=>
          array(5) {
            ["content-type"]=>
            array(1) {
              [0]=>
              string(24) "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
            }
            ["date"]=>
            array(1) {
              [0]=>
              string(29) "Fri, 24 Feb 2017 03:18:58 GMT"
            }
            ["expires"]=>
            array(1) {
              [0]=>
              string(29) "Fri, 24 Feb 2017 03:18:58 GMT"
            }
            ["cache-control"]=>
            array(1) {
              [0]=>
              string(18) "private, max-age=0"
            }
            ["content-length"]=>
            array(1) {
              [0]=>
              string(1) "9"
            }
          }
          ["headerNames":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=>
          array(5) {
            ["content-type"]=>
            string(12) "content-type"
            ["date"]=>
            string(4) "date"
            ["expires"]=>
            string(7) "expires"
            ["cache-control"]=>
            string(13) "cache-control"
            ["content-length"]=>
            string(14) "content-length"
          }
          ["protocol":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=>
          string(3) "1.1"
          ["stream":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=>
          object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream)#195 (7) {
            ["stream":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
            resource(21) of type (stream)
            ["size":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
            NULL
            ["seekable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
            bool(true)
            ["readable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
            bool(true)
            ["writable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
            bool(true)
            ["uri":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
            string(10) "php://temp"
            ["customMetadata":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
            array(0) {
            }
          }
        }

.....
```

What should I do :(

Comment: Try to check if you follow properly the steps in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/batch) on how to make Batching requests with the Google Classroom API especially the [format](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/batch#format-of-a-batch-request) of it. You can also check the PHP example code of batch request [here](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/batch#using-client-libraries).